# Sollte man auf der Frageseite grundlegende Regeln aufführen?

Tags: discussion

Ich finde die [Frageseite](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) zu niedrigschwellig, will heißen zu oft werden grundlegende Dinge nicht beachtet, warum sind auf der Frageseite nicht grundlegende Regeln oder gerne auch weniger einschränkend wirkende Tipps aufgeführt? Die Tour ist mir zu allgemein bzw. nicht auf der Frageseite verlinkt.

Unter anderem fallen immer wieder folgende Dinge auf:

1. Fragen werden nicht in Deutsch gestellt.
2. Es wird nach einfachsten Übersetzungen gefragt.
3. Die Frage ist zu komplex oder unklar oder es wird falsch zitiert, es werden keine Referenzen angegeben.

Meine Frage soll als Diskussion dienen, die grundlegende Frage zu erörtern, ob die Frageseite angepasst werden muss/kann, dann sollte man diskutieren, was darauf sollte.

PS: Mit ist bewußt, daß eine höhere Schwelle u.U. weniger Fragen bedeutet, auf der anderen Seite finde ich das Kriterium von [10 questions/day](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language) schlecht, wenn es schlechtere Qualität der Fragen bedeutet.

Answer (score 5):

Erstmal haben wir Regeln, die sich gegen die meisten, wenn nicht alle, von Dir bemäkelten Probleme stellen und setzen diese auch meines Erachtens weitgehend um (durch Frageschließungen u. Ä.). Wenn Du diese verschärfen möchtest oder etwas an deren Umsetzung auszusetzen hast, eröffne bitte getrennte Diskussionen.

Es ist sicher auch unbestritten, dass es schwierig ist, diese Regeln neuen Fragestellern zu kommunizieren, und es hier Verbesserungsbedarf gibt. Nebenbei denke ich, dass eine bessere Kommunikation hier sogar zu einem Ansteigen der Fragen pro Tag führen könnte, da vernünftig gestellte Fragen auch gute Antworten bekommen (dafür haben wir ja die meisten Regeln) und somit die Zufriedenheit der Fragesteller erhöhen. Dieses Problem betrifft übrigens nicht nur uns, sondern Stack Exchange allgemein, z. B. widmet sich die höchstbewertete Antwort auf [Let's Plan the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285889/255554) diesem Aspekt.

Was wir akut tun können, ist die Frageseite anzupassen. Wenige Seiten tun dies zurzeit, aber es ist durchaus möglich, siehe z. B. [English Language & Usage](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) und 
[Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)
. Ich habe [eine Frage](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1231/2594) dazu gestellt, wie dieser Text aussehen soll. Meiner Erfahrung nach wird dies jedoch keine Wunder bewirken, aber schaden tut es sicher auch nicht.