# Neuer Text für »How to Ask« – Let’s change our “How to Ask”

Tags: discussion, status-completed, new-users, user-interface

[Hier](//meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/1224/2594) habe ich vorgeschlagen, dass wir den Text für »How to Ask« auf der [Frageseite](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ändern können, was auf Zustimmung gestoßen ist. Deshalb frage ich nun, wie genau der neue Text aussehen soll.

Die einzige Einschränkung ist, dass der Kasten nicht deutlich größer sein sollte als der Fragekasten, sprich ca. 15 Zeilen (inkl. Leerzeilen) bei ca. 52 Zeichen pro Zeile. Bitte formatiert Vorschläge entsprechend (zwei Leerzeichen vor einem Zeilenumbruch machen diesen sichtbar).

---

[Here](//meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/1224/2594) I proposed to change the text of “how to ask” on the [Ask Question page](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), which was well received. Therefore I am now asking how exactly the new text shall look like.

The only restriction is that the how-to-ask box shall not be much larger than the box for the actual question, which means about 15 lines (incl. blank lines) at about 52 characters per line. Please format your suggestion acoordingly (to break a line, use two spaces followed by a newline).

Comment: I used the top-voted answer. It is a bit on the wordy side, however. If you decide to modify at all, I recommend cutting words so that askers are more likely to read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest:

> **To obtain a useful and quick answer, please
>
>     adhere to the following:**
>
> - Tell us precisely what you want to know.
> - Tell us what you already found or understood.
> - If possible, provide an example and context.
> - If you are asking for a translation, meaning, or
>     similar: [Tell us why a dictionary did not help you.](//meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/628/2594)
> - We [do not translate or proofread texts](//meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/919/2594).
>     Ask about a single, specific problem instead.
>
> Du darfst auch gerne **auf Deutsch** fragen.
>
> If your question is about this website, ask it on [Meta](//meta.german.stackexchange.com)
>   instead.

Comment: Ist es möglich deine Antwort zu einer community answer zu machen? Dann ist es leichter deine Antwort (source) zu kopieren oder direkt zu bearbeiten.

Comment: What exactly do you wish to know? Ist mir zu allgemein, nichtssagend, es hilft kaum die Frage besser werden zu lassen.

Comment: M.E. sollte die Aufforderung zu Quellenangaben, Referenzen bzw. so viel wie möglich Kontext zu zitieren nicht fehlen.

Comment: @Thomas: 1) Erledigt; danke; hatte ich ganz vergessen. 2) Du glaubst gar nicht, wie viele Fragen es gibt, die daran scheitern. 3) Mit Quellenangaben wäre ich vorsichtig, es nicht zu übertreiben. Immerhin kann man nicht für alles Quellen zitieren (aber gegen einen wohlformulierten Satz, der dies berücksichtigt, habe ich nichts einzuwenden). Kontext ist auch gut. Hast Du einen Vorschlag, wie man das einbauen kann?

Comment: Ich habe folgende Dinge geändert, dabei habe ich leider den Zeilenumbruch nicht geschafft:
1. Positivismus, der Poster möchte eine gute und schnelle Antwort
2. Ich habe versucht in Punkt zwei die Angabe Referenzen und Quellen zu verstärken (subtil)
3. Ich habe alle Tips als Punkte gestaltet, das bringt mehr Klarheit

4. Den Link auf das Problem: one question at atime verstehe ich nicht.

Comment: @Thomas: 1) Ich habe auf Basis Deines Vorschlags weitergearbeitet. Beachte, dass “where did you look into?” kein korrektes Englisch ist und Du nicht einfach Fragen und Aussagesätze mit Kommata aneinanderreihen kannst. 2) Alles als Punkte zu gestalten ist nicht sinnvoll, wenn einige der Punkte nicht zur Überschrift passen. Es ist zum Beispiel nicht notwendig auf Deutsch zu fragen, um eine schnelle und gute Antwort zu erhalten. 3) Einen Zeilenumbruch erhältst Du über zwei Leerzeichen + Neuzeile (schau in den Quellcode). 4) Wenn irgendwelche meiner Änderungen unklar sein sollten, frag nach.

Comment: 1) Ich weiß, allerdings empfinde ich Fragen angenehmer und leichter zu verstehen, ich habe versucht es besser zu kombinieren. (siehe meine Antwort)
2) Ich würde da nicht so genau sein, ist einfach schwierig bei dieser Knappheit.

Comment: Anmerkung: deine Antwort finde ich jetzt schon gut, meine Alternative ist nur ein Vorschlag mit kleinen Nunancen.

Comment: Punkt 4 sagt das Gegenteil von dem aus, was wir wollen. Wir wollen gerade keine spezifischen, sondern generalisierte Fragen klären, also eher "Wieso steht *es* vor dem Substantiv" als "Wieso steht *es* vor *Deutsch*" in "Ich mag es, Deusch zu lernen". Du wolltest darauf hinaus, dass man nicht fragen soll "Übersetzt mir *I like learning German*", glaube ich.

Comment: @userunknown: *Wir wollen gerade keine spezifischen, sondern generalisierte Fragen klären […]* – Hmm, fändest Du *single* statt *specific* an dieser Stelle besser? — Nebenbei sehe ich die Spezifizität solcher Beispielfragen wie Deiner als unvermeidbar an. Jemand, der noch nicht weiß, warum da *es* steht, weiß eben auch nicht, was wesentlich dafür ist, dass es da steht oder mit welchem allgemeinen grammatikalischen Phänomen er es zu tun hat.

Comment: Naja, man will 2 Dinge zugleich: Dass klar wird, worum die Frage konkret geht, etwa wenn ein längerer Satz gepostet wird. Und dann soll aber nicht einfach dieser eine Satz beantwortet werden, sondern das allgemeine Problem, das sich im Satz beispielhaft zeigt. Das letzteres schon ein großes Problemverständnis vorraussetzt ist dabei i.d. Tat ein Problem.

Comment: @userunknown: Okay, aber dieses Problem werden wir mit diesem Text nicht lösen können. Was ist jetzt Dein konkretes Problem mit der Formulierung bzw. hast Du einen Vorschlag, wie man es besser machen könnte?

Comment: Der Text soll ja v.a. Anfänger vor häufigen Schwächen der Fragen, die oft zu Schließungen führen, warnen. Mein Eindruck ist, dass die Fragen häufiger zu individuell sind, im Stile von "übersetze mir das mal einer - die Erklärung, der Grund interessiert mich gar nicht" als dass die Frage so gestellt ist, dass man nicht weiß, womit der Frager ein Problem hat. Das kommt aber auch vor.

Comment: @userunknown: *im Stile von "übersetze mir das mal einer - die Erklärung, der Grund interessiert mich gar nicht"* – das sollte der erste Satz des betreffenden Punktes ja gut auffangen.

Comment: @userunknown: Gibt es jetzt noch etwas, dass Du ändern möchtest, oder ist alles geklärt?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

> **To obtain a useful and quick answer, please
>
>     adhere to the following:**
>
> - What exactly do you wish to know?
>     Try to be as precise as possible!
> - Did you search for an answer already?
>     Please provide a simple example, context or link!
> - If you are asking for a translation, meaning, or
>     similar: [Tell us why a dictionary did not help you.](//meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/628/2594)
> - We [do not translate or proofread texts](//meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/919/2594).
>     Ask about a specific problem instead.
>
> Du darfst auch gerne **auf Deutsch** fragen.
>
> If your question is about this website, ask it on [Meta](//meta.german.stackexchange.com)
>   instead.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ich habe den Punkt raus genommen. Wie schon oben geschrieben, stelle bitte deine Version rein, die ist gut und in jedem Fall hilfreich. Danke für deine Bearbeitungen.